# Open PDF in gwt frame with highlighted words

Tags: pdf, iframe, gwt, gwt-2.5

how can i open pdf with highlighted words on gwt frame using java or javascript?

i passed url link to the iframe and it loads the pdf but there is no highlight

gwt version 2.5.1

firefox portable v.24

Comment: passed link example http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#search="PDF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solve by changing or installing pdf viewer plugin adobe acrobat reader to the browser.

The pdf viewer of the frame depends on the browsers pdf viewer

setup plugins for chrome
http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/12/get-reader-or-acrobat-to-work-in-chrome-compact-pdf-output-from-chrome/

to test, use this url example to the browser with adobe acrobat plugin
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#search=word

It works on chrome 42 with adobe reader plugin...